# How can I fix a ceiling fan with 4 lights where only 1 light works?

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling-fan

I bought a used ceiling fan from Craigslist and just installed it. It's a Hampton Bay fixture that takes intermediate size light bulbs. Only one of the four lights works. The weird thing is, if I take the bulb and put it in the opposite side then that works. If I then put another bulb in its place, the extra bulb won't work. Adjacent sides don't work at all. Also when I turned the fan on, it was touching the little part that sticks out from the chain. The light fixture was a little crooked so I bent it back.

How can I fix it?

Comment: It's not likely anybody will be able to help you repair this fixture over the internet, without a lot more information.  Have you tried installing all new bulbs?  Are you sure you wired it properly? Do you have a multimeter, so you can troubleshoot the sockets?

Comment: They were all new bulbs from two different packages.  Yes, wiring has been triple checked, green to green, white to white, black and blue to black.  Its at my parents house and can get this Thursday.  How do I test the sockets?

Comment: If you have a multimeter, you'll check to make sure there is proper voltage at each socket. If you don't have a multimeter; or don't know how to test voltage with a multimeter, you should contact an Electrician.

Comment: Another thing to check is if there is any chance the lamp cannot screw down far enough into the socket to make contact with the center spring contact because of it's shape. If it's close, the contact may be able to be bent upwards slightly to make contact. Before sticking tools in the socket, be sure the power is off at the breaker. If the wall or ball chain switch is wired wrong, you can get a shock unless the breaker is off.

Answer (score 1):

Check the tab in the bottom of the socket that touches bulb when screwed in. Turn off power and bend tab slightly up. If this isn't it, it is a wiring or dimmer issue.

Answer (score -3):

It's not wired correctly. There is some series circuiting going on.
Wire the lights in parallel (or get someone who knows to do it).

Comment: This might be true if anyone besides the light manufacturer had a hand in wiring the individual lights. I don't think that's the case here.